# Making a long question shorter / easier to read

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, editing-help

I've asked a question [Debugging visualizer which targets DateTime doesn't transfer the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67152796/debugging-visualizer-which-targets-datetime-doesnt-transfer-the-value) and added a bounty.

I feel that by its nature, the question is already rather complex. As comments come in with additional suggestions for various tests, I'd like to update the question with my findings. However, it feels as though the question is devolving into a long wall of text.

**How can I make this question easier to read?**

- What information can I prune from the question?
- What organizational techniques can I use? e.g. some kind of table of contents, TL;DR, HTML `details`?

Comment: I find something as simple as a horizontal rule `---` to separate the actual question from the research can sometimes be enough to make it clearer

Comment: Drop "update *" and replace it with better titles, and throw in some proper headers (rather than just bold). Also what Nick said, but that's about it. You can't add a table of contents. Headers don't have IDs (... yet. This may change in 6-8), and HTML stripping means you can't hack any in. Also means you can't link to other bits of your own post if you reference other sections elsewhere.

Comment: As it stands, that question is _very_ readable: No walls of code, and the wall of text is nicely broken into sections with headers and horizontal rules, inline code is marked well. You're using markdown elements like bullets and blockquotes to make it less boring to read.

Comment: I think that as far as making the question easy to read there isn't much more to be done. It looks well laid out and clearly explained. From its current state, it is easy to distinguish the original question and the subsequent edits with additional information, so even if you think it is a wall of text, it really doesn't feel like it to me. Seriously, I would *pay* reputation to answer such a well-formatted question. However I'm no expert in the language/tags you are dealing with, so I cannot say if there's some language-specific thing that should be done to improve it even more.

Comment: Perhaps, in general, another option is to add a TL;DR (a summary) to the top of the question. That makes it easier for the viewer to see a small relevant part and decide whether it's worth their time or whether they lack the knowledge. In your specific case, the paragraph I skipped to to read first is the two-liner snippet + the following part. Maybe this would serve better as an eye-catcher if it were higher on top

Comment: Just as a side note: A way to initially fold long information like logs or so would be nice. It's a shortcoming of the platform, not of the content creators.

Comment: @Trilarion What do you think of `details` / `summary` support?